# What is time stamp in asynchronous transmission?

Tags: clocks

I am new to CS, and learning asynchronous transmission.

> Asynchronous Transmission typically also uses SYNC word/bits to
>   provide occasional time stamp for receiver to synchronise its clock to
>   the transmitter clock.

Could anyone explain more specifically **how time stamp synchronizes the transmitter and receiver clock to reduce clock skew between them (such as the process or mechanism used)?**

Thank you.